# Windows Command Prompt - 'debug' not a recognized command?

Tags: windows, assembly, command-prompt

I have done a few searches on this and surprisingly could not find a solution.
All I am wanting to do is launch Windows command prompt, and using the 'debug' command, access debug mode.

However command prompt keeps responding with: 'debug' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

From previous searches I could only come to the conclusion that is has something to do with the systems environment variables, but don't feel confident enough to change them.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where did you hear about this 'debug' program?  What is 'debug mode'?

Comment: Ah, the good old days. DEBUG was truly a great program. The world would be better if we went back to using DOS. This is what happens when you use text books that are 25 years old.

Comment: Yes definitely, but I think it would be a great learning experience. It's nice to have good idea of how we got to where we are today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using x64 version of Windows? `debug.com` is a 16-bit program and is not shipped with x64 builds since they don't support 16-bit executables.

Comment: Thanks for this input, after retrying the debug command on a x86 version of Windows, command prompt recognized the 'debug' command without a problem.